# objectAtIndex returns SIGABRT error

Tags: objective-c

I have this line:

```
 NSString *objectkey=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[line objectAtIndex:1]];
```

If objectAtIndex:0, it works fine. But if 1, it produces SIGABRT error at runtime.

However, I have another line to confirm that the array "line" has an object at index 1:

```
   NSLog(@"%d",[line count]);
```

This returns 2 to the console.

Why would SIGABRT occur even though an index should exist there?

As for line, it is created like this:

```
for (int i=1;i<=[components count];i++){

    NSArray*line=[[components objectAtIndex:(i-1)] componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
```

"line" is recreated during each loop iteration (I assume this is okay? no release is necessary, from what i understand using the "separated by string" method).

the array "components" contains lines such as:

Recipe Books|BOOKS

Recipe Photos|PHOTOS

I have created this little loop to verify that all are strings in "line":

```
 for( NSObject* obj in line )
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",obj);
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]==YES) { NSLog(@"string"); }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? Any code for <code>line</code>?

Comment: you may also want to log if the class is not a string when you loop through line and NSLog things.

Comment: Can you verify what the full error is with the uncaught exception log from the console?  I'm pretty sure that the data you're putting into `components` isn't exactly what you think it is.  A simple `NSRangeException` (you tried to access an `NSArray` out of bounds) shows only 'Program received signal "SIGABRT"' in the code window in Xcode 4.  The console is clear about what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the object contained at `[line objectAtIndex:1]` is not an `NSString*`.  Why don't you try iterating over the set of objects in `line` and outputting them with `NSLog`.  My guess is that the second one is going to print an address (of the form `<Classname: 0x0>`, not a string.

```
for( NSObject* obj in line )
{
   NSLog(@"%@",obj);
}
```

Add an `NSLog` to the code where you create `line`:

```
for (int i=1;i<=[components count];i++){
    NSLog(@"%@",[components objectAtIndex:(i-1)]);
    NSArray*line=[[components objectAtIndex:(i-1)] componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
```

---

I have a strong feeling that your input data is bad, as you've excluded our prior answers as the solution with your responses.  Your input data might have a `<cr>` somewhere it doesn't belong or missing data.  How big is the input file for `components`?

---

#### Second answer based on gdb results

Try using `[NSString stringWithString:[line objectAtIndex:1]]` instead of `stringWithFormat`.  Based on your use of `gdb` its likely that `stringWithFormat` is breaking on the unexpected control character (and trying to format it).  `stringWithString` should copy the string character by character.  Removing the control character(s) is another problem. :)

Comment: Good idea. So I ran the exact code you provided here. The results were as expected; all output console lines are text, following what I'd expected based on the "components" array I mention above:

i.e.

    `2011-05-27 14:19:09.511 app[5626:207] SCORES 
    2011-05-27 14:19:09.511 app[5626:207] Music Sheets`

Comment: More debugging is necessary based on your responses.  My first guess is that you're iterating over `components` many times and it works 99% of the time but maybe one piece of input data is wrong.  See my updated answer.

Comment: note my comment below to the other commenter, you are correct I believe, as I found something in the debugger that does not show up in NSLog as it is a non-printing character.

Comment: thanks, indeed it was a problem with the input data. there was a single line which would create only a single index for the array, whereas all the others create 2 indexes. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a valid object at index 1 of your line NSArray, the likely answer is that it's not a NSString, it's some other class that can't be translated using %@ in your stringWithFormat: call.  Look at the stack where it aborts and you could also check the type of the object before calling the stringWithFormat: call.

Comment: how do i look at the stack at the place the program aborts? @slycrel

Comment: if you debug rather than run then you should be able to see the stack trace in your debugger when it crashes.  Make sure that you are not running your release target though as this can sometimes be not what you'd expect to see.  You should be able to identify your code and then also see some of the internal apple call names (though not code) that are actually giving you the SIGABRT.

Comment: also, if you break on the line in question you should be able to print your line array to the debugger console using "po line".

Comment: i'm not sure where you enter "po line", but I did look at the debugger and revealed that the "line" array was showing its second index as "something /r" which I assume to mean a hard return, and perhaps this /r is causing the issue. question is, how to have the /r be ignored when i call that index from the array?